# Why does some binary tree traversal functions take a double pointer?

Tags: c, pointers, binary-tree, traversal, inorder

I was reading about trees and a possible implementation of the 3 traversal functions (from : Data Structures Using C and C++).
The Node struct is :

```
struct node
{
    int info;
    node* left;
    node* right;
}node;
```

`typedef struct node * nodeptr ;`

The implementation of Preorder traverse took a simple pointer of type node:

```
void preorder(node *root);
```

But when it came to Inorder function, it was declared as following :

```
void inorder(nodeptr *root)
```

If I'm not mistaken, and since I looked it up online, in this case nodeptr* would mean ** node right ?
If that's the case, why are we declaring a double pointer of type node for a traverse function ?

Another thing,

```
inorder(root→left);
```

if root is a double pointer of type node, can we actually write root->left to access the attributes of the node it points to ? (as if it were a simple pointer) ?

Edit: I'm just copying what was written in the book and what was given in class. I just had a hard time understanding why, that's all.

Comment: Do not spend your time investigating bad programs.:)

Comment: Look at the implementation of it. For example some implementations of linked lists are working with `**` in order to avoid some extra boundary condition checks.

Comment: BTW `typedef struct node * nodeptr ;` the typedef can be considered bad style (hiding a pointer behind a typedef) The pointer-to-pointer is also not needed here, since the function does not need to change the tree (or its root pointer) Final question: `&(*pp)->left`

Comment: `void inorder(nodeptr *root)` means `void inorder(struct node **root)`

Comment: Looks like it's a typo and they should have written `node *` or `nodeptr`.

Comment: @Ahmed Mejbri  It is not a rare case when a book is written by an author who is unable to write programs or demonstrates a bad style of programming in his books.:) Moreover book code examples can contain typos.

Comment: Thank you all guys, I might as well just drop it and write mine. 
joop thanks for answering that last bit :D

Comment: There is no type `node` defined in your snippet.

Comment: Without seeing the implementations of `preorder()` and `inorder()`, it's anybody's guess why they take different argument types.  Normally you'd only pass a pointer to a pointer if you wanted the function to write a new pointer value to the parameter, but I can't think of a reason why `inorder` would need to do so if `preorder` doesn't.  It's either a typo (they happen) or a badly-written example (they happen, too, all too often).   As for the second question, if `root` has type `node **`, then you'd access the `left` member as `(*root)->left` or `(**root).left`.

Comment: This link can enlighten you: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/linus-torvalds-double-pointer-approach-rohan-verma/?articleId=8534015600813880253

Comment: @VladfromMoscow There are circumstances where this is a very good thing.